# Node.js can't find module './index.js' after installing npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

After installing a node package named "sensit-sigfox", how described with `nmp install sensit-sigfox --save` I get an `Error: Cannot find module './index.js'`.

I use `require('./index.js');` in my code.

The actual file strukture in my project folder is: ./node_modules/sensit_sigfox/index.js

It seems to be an common error but I can't find the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

isnt it:

```
const x = require('sensit-sigfox')
```

Regardless post an ls -l of your ./node_modules directoy it should help indicate what the right include is.

Note: alwats require the package in as the same name you npm installed it unless you have done something atypicall like renaming the dir/package (and don't do that unless you are an expert, and even then think 2x).

Comment: Ok thanks, now it works. In the documentation it was described with require('./index.js');.

Comment: @Karol-Kahn Make sure folks don't sucombe to the same problem: 1. fork the repository, modify the notes and submit a PR (maybe they will merge it in) OR 2. Accept this answer as correct. OR both.